# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_id'

Tags: c#, jquery, telerik

[image]

```
 var windowTelerikId = this.get_id();
```

Comment: I have added the below js files but still the error persist
jquery-2.1.4.min.js   
jquery-1.8.2.js  
 jquery-1.8.2.intellisence.js
 jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of allf 'this' is an object then please try below code

```
$(this).attr('id')

//or

$(this).prop('id')
```